# VBA Macro stumbles on workbook name IF command

Tags: vba, excel

This code I have cobbled together for collating content from a named worksheet from all open workbooks seems to run fine on my computer, but not on the clients.

Whats going wrong here? I believe we are running the same version of excel, and using identical workbooks to test with.

It gets stuck on line 22:

> ```
>         wkb.Worksheets(sWksName).Copy _
>           Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
> ```

Sorry I don't have the error message!

```
    Sub CopyandCollateQuery1()

With Application                        ' Scrubs settings that slow process
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


    Dim wkb As Workbook                 ' Dim Variables
    Dim sWksName As String
    Dim Title1 As Range
    Dim Title1end As Range
    Dim NewRng As Range
    Dim check As String

    sWksName = "Query1"                 ' Sets Worksheet to be collated

    For Each wkb In Workbooks           ' Pulls said worksheet title from each open workbook and copies into macro workbook
        If wkb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            wkb.Worksheets(sWksName).Copy _
              Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        End If
    Next
    Set wkb = Nothing

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
            If .Name <> "Collated" Then
                rowscount = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("B3" & ":" & "B" & rowscount).Copy
                Worksheets("Collated").Activate
                Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    End With
Next ws

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
    Rows(1).Delete
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Total Combined Count"
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
            Set lol = ws.Name
            If .Name <> "Collated" Then
                i = 4
                Do While i < rowscount + 1
                check = .Range("B" & i).Value
                checknum = .Range("B" & i).Offset(0, -1).Value

                Sheets("Collated").Activate
                Worksheets("Collated").Range("A:A").Find(check, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate

                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + checknum
                checknum = 0

                i = i + 1
                Loop

            End If
    End With
Next ws

With Application                        ' undoes initial processes scrub
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

It's also having trouble finding the correct last row when performing the collating action, so I will need to adjust that. But that's beside the point.

Comment: *"Sorry I don't have the error message!"* Why?

Comment: Have you made sure that the `Query1` sheet is available in each of the opened excel workbooks on the test systems ?

Comment: Have you checked the client doesn't have a `Personal Macro Workbook` (`Personal.xlsm` or `Personal.xls`) - this hidden workbook probably won't have a `Query1` sheet.

Comment: collapsar: I suspect that's whats doing it xD

Comment: So how do I get out of the this 'out of subscript range' problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in your code the For loop `For Each wkb In Workbooks` is used to ***Pull said worksheet title from each open workbook and and copy into macro workbook***. That means it looks for the sheet `Query1` in all the open workbooks and when any of the workbook do not have a sheet named `Query1` it throws `Subscript out of range` error.

You can tackle this error in two ways:
**1.** Make sure all your workbooks has sheet `Query1` (don't think this will always happen)
**2.** Use error handling in your code

```
For Each wkb In Workbooks
    If wkb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        On Error Resume Next        '<--- add this line in your code
        wkb.Worksheets(sWksName).Copy _
            Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    End If
Next
```

***On Error Resume Next*** resumes execution ignoring any error thrown on the next line of code. Please note that On Error Resume Next does not in any way "fix" the error. It simply instructs VBA to continue as if no error occurred. For details see this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm).